# In fresh app (similar to nextjs for deno) I can't get an API call to wait for a button push. It runs on page load

Tags: request, get, server-side-rendering, deno, freshjs

I am making a Fresh app (which is a next-gen web framework that works with Deno). I understand the structure of the app and how it handles routing and I made a modified version of the search page from the fresh website https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/getting-started/form-submissions.

```
// routes/search.tsx
import Layout from '../components/layouts.tsx';
import { Handlers, PageProps } from "$fresh/server.ts";

const NAMES = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Dave", "Eve", "Frank"];

interface Data {
  results: string[];
  query: string;
}

export const handler: Handlers<Data> = {
  GET(req, ctx) {
    const url = new URL(req.url);
    const query = url.searchParams.get("q") || "";
    const results = NAMES.filter((name) => name.includes(query));
    return ctx.render({ results, query });
  },
};

export default function Page({ data }: PageProps<Data>) {
  const { results, query } = data;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <form>
        <h1 class="text rounded-lg p-4 my-8"> Search </h1>
        <input class="center rounded-lg p-4 my-8" type="text" name="q" value={query} />
        <br />
        <button
            class="px-5 py-2.5 text-sm font-medium bg-blue-600 rounded-md shadow disabled:(bg-gray-800 border border-blue-600 opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed)"
            type="submit">Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <br />
      <ul>
        {results.map((name) => <li key={name}>{name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

But the problem is that the search function runs before I click the button. On page load, all of `const NAMES` are printed on the webpage.
[image]

So how do I make the app wait until I push submit to do a search?

P.S. I navigated to `localhost:8000/search` in the url bar, it redirected to `http://localhost:8000/search?q=` because as soon as I hit enter the search funtion runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when the search term is not set in the url then `query` is set to an empty string. Therefore `results` is filtered on an empty string so it returns all the results.

A solution would be to return an empty `results` array if the query is not supplied.

```js
export const handler: Handlers<Data> = {
  GET(req, ctx) {
    const url = new URL(req.url);
    const query = url.searchParams.get("q") || "";
    // const results = NAMES.filter((name) => name.includes(query));
    let results: string[];
    if (query === "") {
      results = [];
    } else {
      results = NAMES.filter((name) => name.includes(query));
    }
    return ctx.render({ results, query });
  },
};
```